# Select last class within attribute (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say I have this element:

```
<div id="myElement" class="example1 example2 test">My name is Nanoo</div>
```

How could I go about selecting the last class? (which is `test`)

Something like:

```
$("#myElement")[0].getLastClass();
```

Which responds with...
`"test"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `.attr('class').split(' ').pop()` should work!

```js
console.log($('#myElement').attr('class').split(' ').pop());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myElement" class="example1 example2 test">My name is Nanoo</div>
```

Comment: This just came to my head! (I'm dumb) However, thanks for the answer. I have recently accepted an answer on a different post, so I can accept it in 9 minutes.

Comment: @Nanoo – I'm glad it helped! _Happy Coding_

Comment: `pop()` is a useful function. I was originally going to use `slice(-1)` (which does the same thing), although your example converts the class straight into a string! Thanks again.

Comment: I forgot to accept your answer - sorry! I will accept it now.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by this:

```js
($('#myElement').attr('class')).split(' ')[(($('#myElement').attr('class')).split(' ')).length-1]
```

```js
console.log(($('#myElement').attr('class')).split(' ')[(($('#myElement').attr('class')).split(' ')).length-1])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myElement" class="example1 example2 test">My name is Nanoo</div>
```